# Extract Text from from multiple tags, such as h1 and p tags that has a class, with BeautifulSoup and Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have figured out how to extract text from the `itemprop` but I cannot extract text from the `<div clas="someclass">Extract This Text Here!</div>` I have pasted just the part of my code that isn't working but will paste the entire thing if I need to.

I have set up a variable with BeautifulSoup and Python to get the page but it wont grab just the text.

Edit: Some Text is wrapped in an `h1` tag and some text is in a `p` tag with multiple spans.

Edit 2: So some of data is inside a `<div class=“someclass”><h1>There’s the text</h1></div>` and the other is in `<p class=“anotherclass”><span>This is another text</span></p>`. How do I extract the text from multiple tags?

```
for each_business in info:
    yp_bus_url = each_business.find('a', {'class': 'business-name'}).get('href')
    whole_url = "https://www.yellowpages.com"+yp_bus_url
    print(whole_url)
    bus_page = requests.get(whole_url)
    bus_soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    # The variable below wont get text. I've tried different variations with it too but it doesn't work.
    business_name = bus_soup.findAll("div", class_="sales-info")
    print(business_name)
```

Comment: Are you certain `page.text` actually contains the desired element?  Have you printed it to be sure?

Comment: Have you tried a more basic search, say `bus_soup.findAll("div")`, and printed those results?

Comment: I have printed those out and the info is there.

Comment: Your description "Some Text is wrapped in an h1 tag and some text is in a p tag with multiple spans" doesn't seem to match the code.  The code isn't looking for any `h1` or `p` tags.

Comment: Edit your question to include that output.

Comment: Okay I’ll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the html you've given in the question to extract the text inside `<p>` and `<div>` tag. I hope this is what you are looking for

```
html='''<div class="someclass"><h1>There’s the text</h1></div><p class="anotherclass"><span>This is another text</span>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
print(soup.find('div',class_='someclass').text)
print(soup.find('p',class_='anotherclass').text)
```

> **Output**
>   There’s the text
>   This is another text

Comment: I keep getting this error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'` both when I set it to a variable or if I run it in print.

Comment: Your solution worked. After inspecting the html, I found out that the tags I am looking for aren't even in there. It looks like the html page that is rendered in python is completely different than the page rendered on a browser.